# Is star closure of reverse of grammar equivalent to reverse of closure of that grammar

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, closure-properties

I need to proof if that it's true or not. $ (G^R)^* = (G^*)^R $

If $G$ is a CFG and $ G = \langle V, \Sigma, \delta, S \rangle $ where
$ V $ = Set of Variables or Non-Terminal Symbols
$ \Sigma $ = Set of Terminal Symbols
$ \delta $ = Set of Production Rules
$ S $ = Start Symbol

By def. 
$$ 
G^R = \langle V \ ,\  \Sigma \ ,\  \{X \rightarrow \ u^R | \ (X \rightarrow u) \ \epsilon \ \delta \}\ ,\  S \rangle  
$$

$$
G^* = \langle V \ \cup \ \{S'\} \ , \ \Sigma \ ,\  \delta \ \cup \ \{S' \rightarrow S'S \ |\ \lambda\} \ , \  S' \rangle
$$

Then I tried the following

$$
(G^R)^*= \langle V \ \cup \ \{S'\} \ , \ \Sigma \ ,\  \{X \rightarrow \ u^R | \ (X \rightarrow u) \ \epsilon \ \delta \} \ \cup \ \{S' \rightarrow S'S \ |\ \lambda\} \ , \  S' \rangle
$$
and
$$
(G^*)^R = \langle V \ \cup \ \{S'\} \ , \ \Sigma \ ,\  \{X \rightarrow \ u^R | \ (X \rightarrow u) \ \epsilon \ \delta \} \ \cup \ \{S' \rightarrow S S' \ |\ \lambda\} \ , \  S' \rangle
$$

I do not know how to continue, I haven't found any counterexample

Comment: Does the claim hold for languages, with the usual definitions? Can you connect the two?

Comment: Yes. I have the demonstration with languages $(L^R)^* = (L^*)^R$ 

I can say that if a grammar $G$ generates a language $L$, with proof that $(L^ R)^* = (L^*)^R then (G^R)^* = (G^*)^R$ ?

Comment: What is the effect of the two operations on the language generated by the grammar?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by what effect they have on the generated languages. The Kleen Star operation generates all the words of the language and the reverse operation the reverse of these. In a grammar, the star operation adds a new symbol to generate the concatenation of 0 or more words of L and the reverse operation applies the reverse to the right parts of the rules.

Comment: The real question is whether you're interested in equality of *grammars* or in equality of *the languages they generate*. The latter is discussed in my previous comment. If the former, then you first have to define when two grammars are equal; once you do, take any grammar, compute both sides of the equation, and see whether they're equal. If they aren't (which will be the case), then you have found a counterexample.

Comment: Equality of grammars.

Comment: In that case, you can take the empty grammar and see what happens in both cases.

Comment: With the empty grammar ($S \rightarrow S$) you have an infinite concatenation of the rule ($SSS...S\lambda$ or $\lambda SSSS...$) with a lamda in front or behind depending on the case.

Comment: The empty grammar has no rules at all. When you apply the transformation star, you get a grammar with two rules. You never get an infinite concatenation of anything. Try applying the definition  literally.

Comment: Okay. If the set of rules is empty, when applying the tranfosmation star I would have $S' \rightarrow S' | \lambda$ in both cases, no?

Comment: No. Try applying the transformation just as they're written, without any simplifications. Don't try to be smart. Just follow the definitions literally.

Comment: Sorry, but now I can't see it.

Comment: $S \rightarrow S$ defines the empty grammar, no? Because, you can't get any word in a finite number of steps.

Comment: The empty grammar has no productions at all. Its set of productions is the empty set. The Wikipedia definition, for one, allows this.

Comment: I do not see how empty grammar can help me. Sorry.

Comment: It doesn't help you, it's just the simplest example. You can actually take any grammar at all, and it will be the case that $(G^R)^* \neq (G^*)^R$.

Comment: I did not understand it because I confuse the equality of grammars with equivalence of grammars. So if it is obvious that  $ (G^R)^* \ne (G^*)^R $. Thanks